# Using Complex Analysis to calculate a limiting integral. [question is wrong]

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

**EDIT (please read):** As @en3trix correctly noted, my "proof" is flawed in the sense that $f$ having a "polarity" implies that $f$ is real which is not the case for all analytic functions. I went to check on the question, however, it was deleted. I dug a bit deeper and I saw, what I presume to be the same account (now deleted), asking a very similar question ([Prove that $ \lim_{r\to 0^+} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\log|v(re^{i\theta})|d\theta=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4214444/prove-that-lim-r-to-0-int-02-pi-logvrei-thetad-theta-0)) but this time giving a specific function and claiming the integral to be zero. Now that would be in contradiction to the contention from the previous question (as the log of that function is non zero). One could only guess, but I think that the author misquoted the question in the original post and then deleted it and then decided to post the correct question. In any case, this contention seems to be false. Apologies for the time wasted for those of you who gave this a crack and got to nowhere.

**The problem:**

A few days ago I saw a question (which I will try to link) about proving that

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log(|f(re^{i\theta})|)d\theta=2\pi\log|f(0)|,$$
where $f$ is analitic on $C$. Also $\log$ here is for the complex plane with the negative real axis cut off.

Before I get on with my attempt, I should note that the question could already be answered, however, I don't want to spoil the exercise for myself in the case I have it wrong.

**My attempt:**
Assume $f(0)\neq0$. By the open mapping theorem, $f$ is an open mapping. It follows that the disc of radius $\epsilon$ centred at $0$ gets mapped to a disc centred at $f(0)$ of some radius $\delta$, where $\epsilon, \delta>0$ and are small. For sufficiently small $\delta$ (and $\epsilon$ really) the polarity of $f(z)$ near $f(0)$ will be the same. So $\log |f(z)|$ is continious (which is needed for the later analycity claim). So we have (for $r<\delta$)
$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log(|f(re^{i\theta})|)d\theta=\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^{+}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log(|f(re^{i\theta})|)d\theta=\lim_{r\rightarrow0^{+}}\oint_{D_r}\frac{\log(|f(z)|)}{ iz}dz$$

As $f\neq0$ in the neighbourhood, $\frac{\log(|f(z)|)}{ iz}$ is analytic on that disc except for the origin (where it has a pole). So we can use the residue formula to get
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow0^{+}}\oint_{D_r}\frac{\log(|f(z)|)}{ iz}dz=\frac{2\pi i  \log(|f(0)|)}{i}=2\pi\log(|f(0)|),$$
where $D_r$ is the circle centered at the origin of radius $r$.

**Question 1:** Is this correct, and if not, where is the mistake?

**Question 2:** For $f(0)=0$, is the limit not defined? Moreover, if not, how does one mathematically justify that?

Comment: Please make subject lines informative as to the mathematics of the post, not about you or your future plans.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I fixed it, hopefully, that is better. Do let me know if there is anything else I can do to make it clearer.

Comment: @mjw what I had written is wrong. I think I have fixed it. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. I have now fixed that too.

Comment: Why is $\log (|f(z)|)/z$ analytic? What causes me trouble is $|f(z)|$

Comment: @en3trix thank you for the comment, the reason it is analytic is that for a small enough radius $r$ all of the values of $f(z)$ will be close by, and since we have assumed that $f(0)\neq 0$ it follows that their polarity must be the same. Thus one can write $\log|f(z)|=\log(k f(z))$ where $k$ is a constant either $-1$ or $1$ depending on the value of $f(0)$. This establishes the continuity and from where we can argue by the definition of a logarithm, and using the fact that $f$ is analytic, that the quoted function is analytic on the punctured disk. I hope that makes sense, if not let me know

Comment: @MathsWizzard Thanks for your response. However, note that $\log(|f(z)|)$ has constant imaginary part, since $|f(z)|$ is real, then it can be analytic only if it is constant, which implies $|f(z)|$ is constant, and hence also $f$. On the other hand, I do not understand what you mean when you say the polarity of $f$ is the same locally, since $f$ is complex valued $|f(z)|=kf(z)$ with $k=1,-1$ only can be true when $f$ is real valued.

Comment: @en3trix I think you are right. I also think there is a mistake in the question. I will do an edit in the following minutes,

Comment: @MathsWizzard Yes, I believe the question had a mistake, even when the fact is true: since $f(0)\neq 0$ then,  for $r$ small, the maximum and minumum of  $\log(|f(re^{it})|)$ in $t$ are defined and almost $\log(|f(0)|)$, then the integral of $\log(|f(re^{it})|)$ is bounded from below and above and these bounds tend to each other and to the value $2\pi \log(|f(0)|)$, hence the value of the integral must be also this. However, I believe the question had a mistake because to prove it, one only needs to use continuity, and it seems more an exercise of calculus rather than complex analysis.